# Closing drawer when navigating to current activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am working with the navigation drawer, and having a small problem. The problem occurs When I am in my an activity, and navigate to that same activity though the navigation drawer. The activity launches new (screen  popping up).

I would like the drawer to just close when the user attempts to navigate to the activity they are currently on.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just check the current Activity, pseudocode:

```
if (this instanceof SomeActivity){
    closedrawer();
}else{
    navigate to SomeActivity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//global reference
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;

//instantiate onCreate()
mDrawerLayout= (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

//close it some where, on button click...
if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)) {
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the method you handle clicks from the navigation drawer:

```
// This is for the case where the user is trying to open a fragment called `NewFragment`
Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(NewFragment.TAG);
if (currentFragment == null) {
   NewFragment newFragment = new NewFragment()
   FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment, NewFragment.TAG);
   transaction.commit();
}
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
```

This works if you have added your fragments to the fragment container with the tag. I usually keep this as a `public static final String` in the respective fragments. For instance, `NewFragment` has a static `String` called TAG that is can be used to find it later using the fragment manager.

If the `currentFragment` is null, it means that is not currently added to the manager's activity nor on the back stack. In that case add the new fragment to the fragment container. If not, just simply close the navigation drawer.